# Python IDLE won't import matplotlib even though it is installed

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, ide

I installed matplotlib for python 2.7 on my Windows computer using pip install and shows up as being installed when I type pip list but when I try to import it in the IDLE it returns Importerror: no module named "matplotlib". Is there any way to fix this or is there a reason for this? Anything would be appreciated

Comment: Have you tried restarting the editor, and/or your pc?

Comment: are you using the right python version? if it's installed on python 2.7 but you are using 3.x, this might be a problem.
also, try using another editor (e.g., jupyter-notebook) or even deleting matplotlib and reinstall it.

Comment: Using another editor seems to work for whatever reason thank you!